# How to create a Language Picker using HTML Select, with Option Values having the HREF for the particular language page?

Tags: jquery

Say while in the English page, the Language Picker Select Box text is "EN", and then I select Spanish option "ES" to reach the respective Spanish page.

Then, but by clicking the browser back button, it takes me back to the English page, and there Language Picker Select Box text still remains as "ES". Despite, the English page have (selected="selected") attribute on "EN" option.

```
<select id="lang-picker" onchange="location = this.value;">
   <option id="english" value="/index.html" selected="selected">EN</option>
   <option id="spanish" value="/es/index.html">ES</option>
</select>
```

I am using [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com) CSS framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the browser restores the state of the page, it doesn't just reload the page from scratch. So the newly-selected Spanish option is still selected.

To avoid that happening, re-select the English option in your `change` event handler. The minimum-changes way would be to change your `onchange` to:

```
onchange="var dest = this.value; this.value = this.options[0].value; location = dest;"
```

...but I strongly urge you to look at modern event handling rather than using `onxyz`-attribute-events. For instance, you could remove that `onchange` entirely and add this JavaScript code using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in a `script` element at the end of the body (just before the closing `</body>` tag).

```
document.getElementById("lang-picker").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var dest = this.value;
    this.value = this.options[0].value;
    location = dest;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd snippet is not working for me. Only the first one - "onChange" worked.

Comment: Also, i would like to have full-forms - "English" and "Espanol" in the revealed Select Dropdown, and only "EN" & "ES", as the Select Box title, after choosing. Please note that, "value" attribute is already in use for the HREF links. I am already using "title" attribute for the full-forms. Appreciate your response :)

Comment: Is that strongly recommended to go without "onChange"? WIll it cause any problem, Mr. Crowder?

Comment: @kavin - The second snippet works just fine if you do what I described: Ensure the `script` tag is at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. You can use `onchange` attribute-style event handlers if you like, but putting that much code inside an attribute just isn't best practice. As for showing the full language name, review the basics of `select` elements. It's just a matter of using a label that's different from the value.